# Generate html Rmarkdown with figures inside panels

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have been generating R markdown html files using the `rmdformats::material` style for some time, without problems. But, since the last R and markdown update, some things have changed.

In the past, my html files were printed figures this way (also, see the html code for the printed figures):

[image][image]

But now, they are printed this way:

[image][image]

As you can see, panels framing each figure have disappeared, and I don't know if there is any R markdown option to bring them back.

Here is the code of the R markdown options, and the chunk generating the plots:

````
---
title: "<span style='font-size: 25px'><b>TITLE</b></span>"
subtitle: "<span style='font-size: 22px'><u>Project: ISA</u></span>"
author: "Me"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d/%m/%Y")`'
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
    self_contained: true
    fig_caption: true
    thumbnails: false
    gallery: true
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 12
---
<style>
body {
text-align: justify;
font-size: 12pt}
</style>

```{r EBV_surv, fig.height=6, fig.width=16}
    # First, I generate the table (not included)
    ggpubr::ggarrange(nrow = 1, ncol = 2, align = "hv",
                      ggplot(drop_na(TabEBV_1) %>% group_by(Challenge) %>% summarise(GEBV_mean = mean(EBV)), 
                             aes(x = Challenge, y = GEBV_mean, group = 1)) +
                        geom_line(color = 2, linewidth = 1.2) + geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
                        ggtheme,
                      ggplot(drop_na(TabEBV_1), aes(x = Tank_I_U, y = EBV, fill = Tank_I_U)) + 
                        geom_boxplot(color = "black") + 
                        facet_wrap(~ Challenge, ncol=1) + 
                        ggtheme + theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1)))
    
    ggpubr::ggarrange(nrow = 1, ncol = 2, align = "h",
                      ggplot(drop_na(TabEBV_1), aes(x = EBV, y = Weight_I)) + 
                        geom_point(aes(color = Challenge), size = 2) + ggtheme,
                      ggplot(drop_na(TabEBV_1), aes(x = EBV, y = Weight_I)) + 
                        geom_point(aes(color = Survival), size = 2) + ggtheme +
                        scale_colour_manual(values = c("limegreen", "darkorchid")))
```
````

Any ideas??
Thanks!

**EDIT**: As suggested, I tried to use `thumbnails: true` to add the panels. However, this is the result when I do so. As you can see, figures print very small, not adjusting to the specified dimensions.

[image]

Comment: `thumbnails: true` to get this HTML

Comment: The problem is, `thumbnails: true` generates very small figures, not in the specified size

Comment: Not true for me.